# Transferring .py file to .exe with pyinstaller, EXE file show error with PySide2 (has no attribute 'QtPrintSupport')

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyside

i'm creating a calculato in python. I'm trying to convert the final version to executable. Transfer with pyinstaller is going okay. It creates an .exe file, but when i start .exe file, it shows this error:

[image: Error showed when starting .exe]

In file "calculator.py" line 10 is:

`from PySide2 import *`

When i turn it on as a python file, it works properly. I can't find what is causing this error.

Comment: you could update hooks: `pip3 install --upgrade PyInstaller pyinstaller-hooks-contrib`

Comment: Wildcard import is highly discouraged, especially for big packages that have many (and sometimes optional) submodules. At least, explicitly import individual submodules: `from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport` (assuming you *actually* need print support). This will make it easier to pyinstaller to fetch the required modules. If it still doesn't work (and you need printing), add the module manually with the appropriate spec file or command line arguments.

Comment: Thanks, i sorted which parts of library i was using and it went through smoothly. It's all functioning now! @musicamante

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run pyinstaller in a clean enviroment with only the necessary libaries.
Pyinstaller tend to use installed libaries in the enviroment this makes the files larger and slower to run and can give errors. It has solved most of my pyinstaller issues.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by comments, problem was solved by cutting which parts of library i was using and only adding those to the code. So final import looked like this:

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtWidget
```